# What's the easiest method creating glow effect around a semi transparent bitmap?

Tags: winforms, graphics, gdi+, gdi

I'm trying to create in GDI+ an effect similar to Photoshop's outer glow :
[image: Outer glow example]
I was thinking about drawing path around the bitmap edges but I couldn't find any way to receive the bitmap's edge path.

Is there an easy way achieving what I want or I'll have to use complex edge detection algorithm?

I'm up for any suggestions.